# Import styles and images in ES7

Tags: javascript, webpack

I know I can import modules in two ways: using the `import` keyword and the [`import()`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) method-like.

Using Webpack I can also import styles, images and whatnot.

Without Webpack loaders I can only use `import()` for modules right? So how am I suppose to load images in future JS?

Let's say I want to load an image at some point (maybe when the route changes), should I use a fetch request. Is that what Webpack compiled code does behind the scenes? What other options?

Comment: You just load an image by appending an `<img src="">` to the DOM?

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I want to load the image after some time (e.g. after an event) but if I use the DOM the image loads before within the rest of the page.

Comment: You can add it dynamically to the DOM when the event happens, I didn't say that you should add it to the HTML source

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I was convinced the image would load at the initialization of the page but instead, it only loads when you call it, even dynamically in HTML.